# node index.html не запускается

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deploy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я пытаюсь загрузить сайт на сервер, через npm start все работает, а через node index.html не получается. Может написать байтник, который будет вводить в консоль npm start? Подскажите как это сделать.
В самой html все ок, напрягает только что скрипт весь красный [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `node index.html` ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через node можно запускать только js файлы (эксперты могут поправить), но никак не html

В вашем случае я бы посоветовал написать простенький сервак на express, чтобы запускать ваш html

Вот пример файла (учитывая, что вы вроде как юзали create-react-app). Просто создайте в корне проекта index.js и запустите его через node

```js
const path = require("path");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

require("http")
    .Server(app)
    .listen(3000, () => {
      console.log(`listening on *:${3000}`);
    });
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./build/index.html"));
  });

app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

После npm run build? сборщик говорит вам перейти по адресу, где описано как открыть проект(раньше эти команды писались в консоли)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вводишь эти команды и выводится окно с адресом твоего сервера - твой сервак запущен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо
мне нужно выбрать путь на сайте хостинга для запуска через node моего приложения
я сделал так как вы мне сказали, подключился по ssh к серваку, serve -s build у меня заработала, пишет - "Accepting connections at http://127.0.4.0:3000", но если я правильно понял мне нужно адрес поменять, как это сделать?

Comment: не понял. что значит адрес поменять? это приложение готово к загрузке на хостинг, а там уже свой адрес. мб я чего то не понял

Comment: а почему он не поменялся и пишет 127.0.4.0:3000?

Comment: ну ты не занял порт он там и открылся. там еще один адрес есть, по которому все могут зайти) если бы ты занял 3000 порт, он бы на 3001 открылся, или его даже задать можно, это на том же сайте, который он предлагает. но это чисто на своем компе, типа сервер разворачивается. мб я не прав

Comment: а как сделать чтобы он был виден всем

Comment: там же у тебя в окне 2 адреса. первый это локальный адрес, а второй это всем можно показать. в ответе же указал это

Comment: он мне показал только 1 адрес